# Thread safety of calling QObject's method from another (non-qt) thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have two objects which lives in different threads and I'm trying to figure if a pattern used is thread safe or not.

The first object is QObject-derived and lives (was created in) the main Qt thread. The class contains some `Q_INVOKABLE` methods that should be called from QML, some `signal*()` methods defined as `signals:` and some `Emit*()` (normal) methods that I use as wrappers to emit signals. For example:

```
void MyQObjectClass::EmitStatus(void) {
    emit signalStatusChange(_status);
}
```

I normally listen for those signals in QML.

The second object is *not* QObject-derived and lives in a second thread (`pthread`). This thread runs its own event loop (libev) and dispatches events. I can't use anything related to Qt in this thread because I need the custom `libev` event loop. On this object I defined some `Notify*()` methods that will send async events through `libev` to be picked up by callbacks.

I need to be able to communicate between the two objects/threads, but I'm not sure how to safely do this.

The actual design is to let the `pthread` thread object call the different `Emit*()` methods directly so that the QObject can properly propagate the information to Qt/QML. If I need to send information from Qt/QML to the `pthread`/`libev` object I call (from the Qt thread) the `Notify*()` methods.

When reading [Accessing QObject Subclasses from Other Threads](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#accessing-qobject-subclasses-from-other-threads), it says:

> QObject and all of its subclasses are not thread-safe. This includes the entire event delivery system.

but then further it is stated that:

> On the other hand, you can safely emit signals from your QThread::run() implementation, because signal emission is thread-safe.

So my question is, is the design described above thread-safe? Can I safely call `myQObject->EmitMySignal()`, which in turns will call `emit signalMySignal()`, all this from inside the `pthread` object?

Comment: I think you should handle this with `postEvent` rather than directly accessing the `QObject` like that. `postEvent` is thread safe and is designed for this purpose if you don't want to or cannot use normal signal/slot connection.

Comment: Emitting signal is thread safe, as stated. However, reading value of member variable is not thread safe. So you need to protect access to `_status`, if it is accessed from multiple threads. Calling a *QObject* methods from multiple threads is error prone, so if you do it I recommend a few things: 1. divide the methods into "called from other threads" and "normal" methods, and have *distinct naming convention* for these. 2. divide the member variables the same way, and be sure to mutex-protect the access to member variables which are meant to be used from multiple threads. 3. Review the code!

Answer (score 1):

I will demonstrate how to achieve what you want with events instead of signals and slots that you cannot use (because one side is not `QObject` derived)

```
class MyObjectClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    virtual bool event(QEvent *event) override
    {
        bool result = true;

        if(event->type() == QEvent::User+1)
            emit signalStatusChange(_status);
        else
            result = QObject::event(event); //call direct parent's event here!

        return result;
    }
};
```

And in your other thread you will do this:

```
MyObjectClass *p; //holds pointer to the instance in main thread
qApp->postEvent(p, new QEvent(QEvent::User+1));
```

This will retrieve pointer to the app that lives in the main thread and post event to its event loop. The event will be processed asynchronously from the call however so the behaviour will be different than what you are doing now. But it will be safer and imho more elegant. You can add as many types as you need. Do not forget to propagate the event to the parent if you have not handled it though!